# Looping over DataTable contents on aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datatable, html-table

I have an aspx page which contains a 3-page multiview. On the second page I have a asp:listview which allows me to insert/update/delete into a DataTable which I have defined in my aspx.cs file.

This all works fine. I am able to insert into the table and display what is inserted into a table on the webpage just below the insert form.

My question is as follows:

I would like to be able to loop through the table on the 3rd page in the multiview and display the contents stored in the table. How do I "send" the DataTable over to the aspx page?

I imagine that the looping code would be similar to this:

```
   <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <% for( var col in Model.Columns ) { %>
        <th><%= col.ColumnName %>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
      <% for( var row in Model.Rows ) { %>
      <tr>
        <% for( var col in Model.Columns ) { %>
        <td><%= row[col].ToString() %></td>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
      <% } %>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an

```
    <asp:Gridview id="gvMyData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Then in your code behind, just bind your datatable to it.

```
    gvMyData.DataSource = myDataTable;
    gvMyData.DabaBind();
```